# Relay cross reference for 1925-3-2

Tags: electronics, repair

My amateur radio uses 1925-3-2 relays on the low pass filter board to select 
bands. This relay is no longer available.

Is there an alternative I can use? Or something?

Comment: Make of the relay and radio?

Comment: Radio is ten tec paragon. don't know about relay until Monday. thanks

Comment: You likely already found this thread, but it doesn't look promising: http://lists.contesting.com/archives//html/TenTec/2015-10/msg00245.html

Comment: Did you find the relay you need? If not, please supply the part ID (e.g., K1, RX Bandpass Filter board, manual figure 4-16 on page 4-23). A photo of the relay would also be helpful, as it's possible that one of the big manufacturers makes a relay with the same form factor.